# How to get the event type in backbone?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

collection and view in back bone

```
var studentmodel = Backbone.Model.extend();

    var studentcollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model : studentmodel,
url : 'http://localhost/bb/data.JSON',
parse : function(response){
    //console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
    //return response;
},
  });



var studentlistview = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "ul",
    className : "studentlistul",
    initialize : function(){
        this.model.bind("reset", this.checkEvent,this);
        this.model.bind("add", this.checkEvent,this);
    },
      checkEvent : function(){

        $(this.el).html("");

    _.each(this.model.models, function(student){

    $(this.el).append(new studentListItemView({ model : student}).render2().el);
    }, this);

    $('#studentlistdiv').html($(this.el));

    return this;
```

}
    });

and try to add items to this model and its work, my question is that inside render fn how can i get the event type while   this.model.bind("add", this.checkEvent,this) this evt fire. inside checkEvent how can i get the type of event ie which one fired add or reset. this is my question plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reliable way for a Backbone event handler to know what event triggered it. Instead of doing this:

```
this.model.bind("reset", this.checkEvent, this);
this.model.bind("add",   this.checkEvent, this);
```

you should have separate handlers for each desired action:

```
// A reset generally means that you want to redraw the whole thing.
this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);

// If one model is added then you usually just want to render the
// the new one.
this.model.bind("add", this.render_one, this);
```

and then your `render` would look sort of like this:

```
this.$el.empty();
this.collection.each(this.render_one, this);
return this;
```

A couple extra things while I'm here:

1. Backbone views already have a jQuery version of their `this.el` in [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) so there's no need to `$(this.el)`, just use `this.$el`.
2. Backbone views handle the [`collection` option](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) the same way they handle `model`. So if you `new View({ collection: c })` then the view will automatically have `this.collection`. If you have a collection, use `collection` and if you have a model, use `model`; using accurate names is less confusing.
3. Backbone collections have a bunch of [Underscore methods already mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you can say `this.collection.each(...)` instead of `_(this.collection.models, ...)`.